# Solder won't melt

Tags: soldering

I'm trying to remove a solder bridge from this chip. I used flux and solder wick, but the solder on here does not seem to melt. I'm using the Weller PU81 soldering station at 350deg. What do you think is the problem?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You haven't supplied a link to the user manual and you haven't said what temperature setpoint you are using and that's going to be kind of important. Hit the [edit] link ...

Comment: Thank you. What kind of user manual are you talking about?

Comment: That might not be a solder bridge - it could be intentional, as explained in the YouTube vide [EEVblog #1353​ - WHY Are These Pins Shorted?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrYYGS0uZlU). Pins 30 and 31 must be connected according to the [LTC6811 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC6811-1-6811-2.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use a larger (thicker) tip if you have one.
2. Turn up the temperature.
3. **Add** solder to the area you are trying to clean up.
4. Put some solder on the tip of your iron.
5. Put the solder wick down on the spot you are trying to clean up.
6. Put the tip down on the solder wick over the spot you want to clean up.  The blob of solder you put on the tip must be the contact point between the tip and the solder wick.

The original solder may be lead free solder, which requires a higher temperature to melt.

Adding (leaded) solder to it lowers its melting temperature a little.

Putting a spot of solder on the tip and using that blob as the contact improves the heat transfer between the iron and the wick.

Using a short, thick tip helps to transfer heat from the iron heater to the wick.

Comment: By the way, not really the case that lead-free solder always melts at a higher temperature than lead-containing solder: [264 lead-free solder products melting below 222°C](https://www.digikey.de/short/43vnjt) .

Comment: Pins 30 and 31 need to be connected together on the LTC6811, so the problem could be not knowing that.